# Use threads and mutex to keep blocking fwrite outside main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pipe, mutex, fwrite

I would like to have a background thread do the fwrite to avoid blocking the main thread. However this requires not just a locked section but specific sequential access.

As such, the fwrite thread cannot execute until the data is copied to buffer. Also, the generate thread cannot write data into buffer until fwrite thread is done.

So we need to guarantee sequential access to blocks of code by 2 threads. I am unable to solve this problem based on my knowledge of mutexes.

I would prefer to use stdlib and not pthreads.

EDIT:- Here is a sample of a solution I am trying.

The problem reduces to a producer-consumer problem with max 1 element in the queue. Here is a class that will spawn a background thread for the fwrite until signaled to stop. Please help me improve this.

```
/*
 * Some references
 *
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29#Condition_variables
 * https://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs140-spring14/lecture.php?topic=locks
 * http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread
 * https://gist.github.com/dpressel/de9ea7603fa3f20b55bf
 */

class PiperThread {

    FILE* fd_;
    bool errB_;
    ostringstream errSS_;
    int sz_;
    uchar* bufS_, * bufP_;
    int consumed_;
    char errnoS_[1024];
    std::mutex m_;
    condition_variable dataAvailable_, spaceAvailable_;
    clock_t prevTime_;

public:
    PiperThread(const char* cmd, int sz, uchar* buf) {
        consumed_ = 0;
        errB_ = FALSE;
        sz_ = sz;
        bufS_ = buf;
        prevTime_ = 0;
        bufP_ = NULL;

        if (!(fd_ = _popen(cmd, "wb"))) {
            end();
            strerror_s(errnoS_, errno);
            errSS_ << PRODUCT_NAME << " :: _popen: " << errnoS_;
        }
        else {
            setvbuf(fd_, nullptr, _IONBF, 0);
            // Start fwriter thread
            //thread([this] {this->threadFn_(); });
            new thread([this] { while (TRUE) {
                if (errB_)
                    break;
                consume(); } });
        }
    }

    ~PiperThread() {
        errB_ = TRUE;
        if (bufP_)
            bufP_ = NULL;
        spaceAvailable_.notify_all();
        dataAvailable_.notify_all();
    }

    void end() {
        _pclose(fd_);
        errB_ = TRUE;
    }

    bool add(uchar* buf) {

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_);
        spaceAvailable_.wait(lock, [this]() { return (!isFull_() || errB_); });

        if (errB_)
            bufP_ = NULL;
        else {
            memcpy(bufS_, buf, sz_);
            bufP_ = bufS_;
        }

        lock.unlock();
        dataAvailable_.notify_all();

        return !errB_;
    }

    bool consume() {
        clock_t start_time, curr_time = 0;
        int delay = 0;

        if (errB_) {
            bufP_ = NULL;
            return !errB_;
        }

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_);
        dataAvailable_.wait(lock, [this]() { return (!isEmpty_() || errB_); });
        
        if (!errB_) {
            start_time = clock();

            size_t ret = fwrite(bufP_, 1, sz_, fd_);

            if (ret != sz_) {
                strerror_s(errnoS_, errno);
                errSS_ << PRODUCT_NAME << " :: fwrite: " << ret << " bytes written out of "
                    << sz_ << " :: " << errnoS_;
                end();
            }
            else {
                consumed_++;
            }
            fflush(fd_);

            delay = (((curr_time = (clock() - start_time)) > prevTime_)) ? // If current frame was slower
                (delay >= 1000) ? delay : delay + 160 : // then raise delay
                (0 == delay) ? delay : delay - 20; // else reduce delay

            prevTime_ = curr_time;

        }
        bufP_ = NULL;
        lock.unlock();
        spaceAvailable_.notify_all();
        
        if (!errB_)
            Sleep(delay);

        return !errB_;
    }

    int consumed() {
        return consumed_;
    }

    bool error(string& s) {
        if (errB_)
            s = errSS_.str();
        return errB_;
    }

private:

    bool isFull_() const {
        return bufP_;
    }

    bool isEmpty_() const {
        return !bufP_;
    }
};
```

Comment: Use two buffers? Please show a [mre] showing what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: I believe what you describe may be the [producer/consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem), which can be solved with a [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: Just as a side note: The problem you describe would probably be best solved with single-threaded non-blocking/asynchronous I/O and not with multi-threading. However, if your intention is merely to experiment with multi-threading, then using multi-threading to solve your problem would probably be a good exercise.

Comment: You may need to consider the possibility that the fwrite will always be the slow bit. The various filesystem and storage device caches effectively mean there already is some parallelism when writing data, and if those caches are already saturated then there's nothing you can do in your programme to speed them up. You may find that, even if you do what you're planning, it makes no improvement. You can use the system monitor to see what speed the SSD (or whatever) is already achieving, and compare that to its specification.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have added a class for a current solution that I am experimenting with.

Comment: @bazza I cannot assume that fwrite is the bottleneck. In many image processing pipelines, a frame may take a minute to render, and that will be faster than the fwrite.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I think the producer-consumer is a good description. I am looking at promise/future for a possible solution.

Comment: @AnmolMishra: A promise/future is good for one-time use, but I don't think it is a proper solution for the consumer/producer problem (which requires continuous use). Therefore, I believe the solution should use an [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) instead. I will look into the matter further tomorrow, and possibly write my own answer.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I have added a class based on std::condition_variable Please review the edited question as I cannot post an answer from my account.

Comment: @AnmolMishra: Does the line `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);` compile? I don't see any declaration of a variable named `mutex`? Did you maybe mean `m_` instead of `mutex`?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I changed it to m_

Comment: @AnmolMishra: Are you `using namespace std`? If not, then you must write `std::condition_variable` instead of `condition_variable`.

Comment: @AnmolMishra: Apart from that, your code looks good, except maybe how you handle the shutdown. I think it would be better if you add an extra variable to the predicate, which checks whether a shutdown has been initiated, and combine this variable with the existing predicate with `&&`. Otherwise the thread may start waiting on the condition variable again, despite a shutdown having been initiated. However, how you should do this probably depends on which thread initiates the shutdown. I know it is not the consumer thread, but is it the producer thread or a third thread?

Comment: I found one error: The producer function `add` should wait on the `spaceAvailable` condition variable and notify the `dataAvailable` condition variable. Instead, it is notifying the `spaceAvailable` condition variable. The consumer function `consume` has a similar error. It should wait on `dataAvailable` and notify `spaceAvailable`, but it notifies `dataAvailable` instead.

Comment: @AnmolMishra: Good, that bug that I mentioned in my last comment is fixed now. The only thing missing now is the shutdown code. However, I believe you should be able to test your program without shutdown code. You can add the shutdown code later, if you want.

Comment: I have modifed the spaceAvailable and dataAvailable as suggested. This is "using namespace std" . The issue of shutdown is non-trivial. Any error in popen or fwrite needs to shutdown the thread. Also, when the calling producer runs out of data to produce, the thread needs to shutdown (this can be done in the destructor). I do not understand the suggested solution for shutdown. I define a "bool shutdownB" set to FALSE. "shutdownB" is set to TRUE during the destructor. Would you not "|| shutdownB" in the predicate for the wait ? The predicate forces a wait until condition is TRUE.

Comment: @AnmolMishra: Ah, yes, you are right, it should be `||`, not `&&`. I agree that the shutdown code is non-trivial, therefore you might want to test your code first without the shutdown code.

Comment: @AnmolMishra: I don't see anything wrong with that code. However, is that code in the function body of the constructor or is it in the member initializer list of the constructor? If it is in the member initializer list, then I'm not sure of the other data members (which are used by the created thread) have been initialized yet. That could then be the reason for the crash.

Comment: @AnmolMishra: Oh, you have deleted your last comment? Did you settle the issue? What was the problem?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I found that you had to use the new operator to start a thread in the constructor. Otherwise, all the private data comes out corrupted. Also, for some odd reason memcpy and copy operators cause a crash inside the class. If I pass a pointer to the data and use that, there is no issue. Odd...

Comment: @AnmolMishra: It should not be necessary to use the `new` operator in modern C++. Therefore, I don't think that your solution is ideal. However, I cannot judge this without seeing the code.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I have updated the answer with a working solution. However, pipes are very slow and I get timeouts with large amounts of data, so I will stop working on this. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand from your question you want to one thread generate data and another thread consume the data and write to the file. If I am right you could use from package task in c++17 and use from promise and future as follow:

```
  #include <future>
  void writeToFile(){
      std::cout << "Writing  data." << std::endl;
  }
  void waitingForData(std::future<void>&& fut){
      std::cout << "Writer: Waiting for data." <<
      std::endl;
      fut.wait();
      writeToFile();
     std::cout << "Work done." << std::endl;
 }
 void setDataReady(std::promise<void>&& prom){
    std::cout << "Sender: Data is ready." <<
    std::endl;
    prom.set_value();
 }
 std::promise<void> sendReady;
 auto fut= sendReady.get_future();
 std::thread t1(waitingForData, std::move(fut));
 std::thread t2(setDataReady, std::move(sendReady));
```

Comment: @AnmolMishra let me know if this answer works for your question.

Comment: I cannot use a separate thread for data generator as its being used from another app. Sorry I should have mentioned that.